# Svelte - How to make array forEach method reactive to <svelte:window> bindings?

Tags: foreach, svelte

I have this Svelte code that essentially takes a html text from a database and for each tooltip checks whether there may be an overflow on the right side, if so the code flips the tooltip to the left side.

Svelte [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/6c819e2a249241768a132f96fda01bd6?version=3.48.0).

```js
<script>
    import {onMount} from 'svelte'
    
    let newInnerHTML = `<article identifier="061">
         <ti.art>Článek 61</ti.art>
         <sti.art>Změna nařízení (EU) č. 1093/2010</sti.art>
         <alinea>
            <parg>V čl. 4 bodu 2 nařízení (EU) č. 1093/2010 se doplňuje nový podbod, který zní:</parg>
            <quot.s level="1">
               <list type="OTHER">
                  <item>
                     <np>
                        <no.p>
                           <quotstart>"</quotstart>
                           viii)
                        </no.p>
                        <txt>
                           pokud jde o nařízení Evropského parlamentu a Rady (EU) 2019/2033
                           <note note.id="E0028" numbering="STAR" type="QUOTATION">
                              <parg>
                                 Nařízení Evropského parlamentu a Rady (EU) 2019/2033 ze dne 
                                 <date iso="20191127">27. listopadu 2019</date>
                                 o obezřetnostních požadavcích na investiční podniky a o změně nařízení (EU) č. 1093/2010 (EU) č. 575/2013, (EU) č. 600/2014 a (EU) č. 806/2014 (Úř. věst. L 314, 
                                 <date iso="20191205">5.12.2019</date>
                                 , s. 1 ).
                              </parg>
                           </note>
                           a směrnici Evropského parlamentu a Rady (EU) 2019/2034
                           <note note.id="E0029" numbering="STAR" type="QUOTATION">
                              <parg>
                                 Směrnice Evropského parlamentu a Rady (EU) 2019/2034 ze dne 
                                 <date iso="20191127">27. listopadu 2019</date>
                                 o obezřetnostním dohledu nad investičními podniky a o změně směrnic 2002/87/ES, 2009/65/ES, 2011/61/ES, 2013/36/EU, 2014/59/EU a 2014/65/EU (Úř. věst. L 314, 
                                 <date iso="20191205">5.12.2019</date>
                                 , s. 64).
                                 <quotend>"</quotend>
                              </parg>
                           </note>
                           , příslušné orgány ve smyslu čl. 3 odst. 1 bodu 5 uvedené směrnice.
                        </txt>
                     </np>
                  </item>
               </list>
               <div>----------------------</div>
               <note note.id="E0028" numbering="STAR" type="QUOTATION" class="under">
                  <parg>
                     Nařízení Evropského parlamentu a Rady (EU) 2019/2033 ze dne 
                     <date iso="20191127">27. listopadu 2019</date>
                     o obezřetnostních požadavcích na investiční podniky a o změně nařízení (EU) č. 1093/2010 (EU) č. 575/2013, (EU) č. 600/2014 a (EU) č. 806/2014 (Úř. věst. L 314, 
                     <date iso="20191205">5.12.2019</date>
                     , s. 1 ).
                  </parg>
               </note>
               <note note.id="E0029" numbering="STAR" type="QUOTATION" class="under">
                  <parg>
                     Směrnice Evropského parlamentu a Rady (EU) 2019/2034 ze dne 
                     <date iso="20191127">27. listopadu 2019</date>
                     o obezřetnostním dohledu nad investičními podniky a o změně směrnic 2002/87/ES, 2009/65/ES, 2011/61/ES, 2013/36/EU, 2014/59/EU a 2014/65/EU (Úř. věst. L 314, 
                     <date iso="20191205">5.12.2019</date>
                     , s. 64).
                     <quotend>"</quotend>
                  </parg>
               </note>
            </quot.s>
         </alinea>
      </article>
 <article identifier="064">
         <ti.art>Článek 64</ti.art>
         <sti.art>Změny nařízení (EU) č. 806/2014</sti.art>
         <alinea>
            <parg>
               V článku 12a nařízení Evropského parlamentu a Rady (EU) č. 806/2014
               <note note.id="E0038" numbering="ARAB" numbering.continued="YES" type="FOOTNOTE">
                  <parg>
                     Nařízení Evropského parlamentu a Rady (EU) č. 806/2014 ze dne 
                     <date iso="20140715">15. července 2014</date>
                     , kterým se stanoví jednotná pravidla a jednotný postup pro řešení krize úvěrových institucí a některých investičních podniků v rámci jednotného mechanismu pro řešení krizí a Jednotného fondu pro řešení krizí a mění nařízení (EU) č. 1093/2010 (
                     <ref.doc.oj coll="L" date.pub="20140730" no.oj="225" page.first="1">Úř. věst. L 225, 30.7.2014, s. 1</ref.doc.oj>
                     ).
                  </parg>
               </note>
               se doplňuje nový odstavec, který zní:
            </parg>
            <quot.s level="1">
               <parag identifier="012A.003">
                  <no.parag>
                     <quotstart>"</quotstart>
                     3.
                  </no.parag>
                  <alinea>
                     <parg>
                        Pokud jde o požadavky na kapitál na individuálním základě investičních podniků uvedených v čl. 2 písm. c) tohoto nařízení, které nejsou investičními podniky uvedenými v čl. 1 odst. 2 nebo 5 nařízení (EU) 2019/2033, jsou v souladu s článkem 65 nařízení Evropského parlamentu a Rady (EU) 2019/2033
                        <note note.id="E0039" numbering="STAR" type="QUOTATION">
                           <parg>
                              Nařízení Evropského parlamentu a Rady (EU) 2019/2033 ze dne 
                              <date iso="20191127">27. listopadu 2019</date>
                              o obezřetnostních požadavcích na investiční podniky a o změně nařízení (EU) č. 1093/2010 (EU) č. 575/2013, (EU) č. 600/2014 a (EU) č. 806/2014 (Úř. věst. L 314, 
                              <date iso="20191205">5.12.2019</date>
                              , s. 1).
                           </parg>
                        </note>
                        v tomto nařízení odkazy na článek 92 nařízení (EU) č. 575/2013 chápány takto:
                     </parg>
                     <list type="alpha">
                        <item>
                           <np>
                              <no.p>a)</no.p>
                              <txt>odkazy na čl. 92 odst. 1 písm. c) nařízení (EU) č. 575/2013, pokud jde o požadavek na celkový kapitálový poměr, v tomto nařízení se považují za odkazy na čl. 11 odst. 1 nařízení (EU) 2019/2033;</txt>
                           </np>
                        </item>
                        <item>
                           <np>
                              <no.p>b)</no.p>
                              <txt>odkazy na čl. 92 odst. 3 nařízení (EU) č. 575/2013, pokud jde o celkový objem rizikové expozice, v tomto nařízení se považují za odkazy na příslušný požadavek podle čl. 11 odst. 1 nařízení (EU) 2019/2033 vynásobený koeficientem 12,5.</txt>
                           </np>
                        </item>
                     </list>
                  </alinea>
                  <alinea>
                     Pokud jde o dodatečné kapitálové požadavky na investiční podniky uvedené v čl. 2 písm. c) tohoto nařízení, které nejsou investičními podniky uvedenými v čl. 1 odst. 2 nebo 5 nařízení (EU) 2019/2034, považují se v souladu s článkem 65 směrnice Evropského parlamentu a Rady (EU) 2019/2034
                     <note note.id="E0040" numbering="STAR" type="QUOTATION">
                        <parg>
                           Směrnice Evropského parlamentu a Rady (EU) 2019/2034 ze dne 
                           <date iso="20191127">27. listopadu 2019</date>
                           o obezřetnostním dohledu nad investičními podniky a o změně směrnic 2002/87/ES, 2009/65/ES, 2011/61/ES, 2013/36/EU, 2014/59/EU a 2014/65/EU (Úř. věst. L 314, 
                           <date iso="20191205">5.12.2019</date>
                           , s. 64).
                           <quotend>"</quotend>
                        </parg>
                     </note>
                     v tomto nařízení odkazy na článek 104a směrnice 2013/36/EU za odkazy na článek 40 směrnice (EU) 2019/2034.
                  </alinea>
               </parag>
               <div>----------------------</div>
               <note note.id="E0039" numbering="STAR" type="QUOTATION" class="under">
                  <parg>
                     Nařízení Evropského parlamentu a Rady (EU) 2019/2033 ze dne 
                     <date iso="20191127">27. listopadu 2019</date>
                     o obezřetnostních požadavcích na investiční podniky a o změně nařízení (EU) č. 1093/2010 (EU) č. 575/2013, (EU) č. 600/2014 a (EU) č. 806/2014 (Úř. věst. L 314, 
                     <date iso="20191205">5.12.2019</date>
                     , s. 1).
                  </parg>
               </note>
               <note note.id="E0040" numbering="STAR" type="QUOTATION" class="under">
                  <parg>
                     Směrnice Evropského parlamentu a Rady (EU) 2019/2034 ze dne 
                     <date iso="20191127">27. listopadu 2019</date>
                     o obezřetnostním dohledu nad investičními podniky a o změně směrnic 2002/87/ES, 2009/65/ES, 2011/61/ES, 2013/36/EU, 2014/59/EU a 2014/65/EU (Úř. věst. L 314, 
                     <date iso="20191205">5.12.2019</date>
                     , s. 64).
                     <quotend>"</quotend>
                  </parg>
               </note>
            </quot.s>
         </alinea>
      </article>`;
    
    let windowInnerWidthy;
    let windowscrollX;

    onMount(() => { 
        let tooltips = document.querySelectorAll("note:not(.under) parg");
        tooltips.forEach(element => {
         let tooltip = element.getBoundingClientRect();
         let offset = tooltip.left + windowscrollX;
         let width = tooltip.width;
         let smaller  = (offset + width <= windowInnerWidthy);
            if (!smaller) {
                element.classList.add('edge');
            } else {
               element.classList.remove('edge');
            }
        });                                  
                    
    });
</script>
    <svelte:window bind:innerWidth={windowInnerWidthy} bind:scrollX={windowscrollX}/>
<container>
{@html newInnerHTML}
</container>

<style>
:global(ti, preamble\.init, visa, sti, gr\.consid\.init, consid, article, ti\.art, sti\.art, parag, alinea, item)
 {
     display: block;
     padding-top: 5px;
     padding-bottom: 5px;
}
:global(no\.p, no\.parag)
  {
     padding-right: 6px;
}
:global(alinea:first-of-type)
  {
     display: inline 
}
:global(doctitle, ti, ti\.art, sti, sti\.art)
  {
     text-align: center;
}
:global(note)
 {
     display: inline-block;
     position: relative;
}
:global(note:not(.under) parg) 
  {
     visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
     background-color: black;
     color: #fff;
     padding: 5px 5px;
     border-radius: 6px;
     z-index: 1;
     width: 50vw;
     top: 50%;
}
     
:global(.edge)
  {
        right: 0;
     }
:global(note::before)
  {
     content: attr(note\.id);
    font-size: x-small;
    vertical-align: top;
    color: blue;
    padding-left: 6px;
}
:global(note:hover parg)
  {
    visibility: visible;
}
:global(quot\.s)
  {
    background: #ffe574;
    display: inline-block;
}
</style>
```

With the onMount() this works great. The goal is to have it interactive reacting to a user resizing the window, not just with onMount of the component. But I have no clue how to achieve this reactive behavior with forEach method.
This is my code so far:

Svelte [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/49c3a8a5868144d098f56b07dd9fe9ed?version=3.48.0).

```js
<script>
    import {onMount} from 'svelte'
    
    let newInnerHTML = `<article identifier="061">
         <ti.art>Článek 61</ti.art>
         <sti.art>Změna nařízení (EU) č. 1093/2010</sti.art>
         <alinea>
            <parg>V čl. 4 bodu 2 nařízení (EU) č. 1093/2010 se doplňuje nový podbod, který zní:</parg>
            <quot.s level="1">
               <list type="OTHER">
                  <item>
                     <np>
                        <no.p>
                           <quotstart>"</quotstart>
                           viii)
                        </no.p>
                        <txt>
                           pokud jde o nařízení Evropského parlamentu a Rady (EU) 2019/2033
                           <note note.id="E0028" numbering="STAR" type="QUOTATION">
                              <parg>
                                 Nařízení Evropského parlamentu a Rady (EU) 2019/2033 ze dne 
                                 <date iso="20191127">27. listopadu 2019</date>
                                 o obezřetnostních požadavcích na investiční podniky a o změně nařízení (EU) č. 1093/2010 (EU) č. 575/2013, (EU) č. 600/2014 a (EU) č. 806/2014 (Úř. věst. L 314, 
                                 <date iso="20191205">5.12.2019</date>
                                 , s. 1 ).
                              </parg>
                           </note>
                           a směrnici Evropského parlamentu a Rady (EU) 2019/2034
                           <note note.id="E0029" numbering="STAR" type="QUOTATION">
                              <parg>
                                 Směrnice Evropského parlamentu a Rady (EU) 2019/2034 ze dne 
                                 <date iso="20191127">27. listopadu 2019</date>
                                 o obezřetnostním dohledu nad investičními podniky a o změně směrnic 2002/87/ES, 2009/65/ES, 2011/61/ES, 2013/36/EU, 2014/59/EU a 2014/65/EU (Úř. věst. L 314, 
                                 <date iso="20191205">5.12.2019</date>
                                 , s. 64).
                                 <quotend>"</quotend>
                              </parg>
                           </note>
                           , příslušné orgány ve smyslu čl. 3 odst. 1 bodu 5 uvedené směrnice.
                        </txt>
                     </np>
                  </item>
               </list>
               <div>----------------------</div>
               <note note.id="E0028" numbering="STAR" type="QUOTATION" class="under">
                  <parg>
                     Nařízení Evropského parlamentu a Rady (EU) 2019/2033 ze dne 
                     <date iso="20191127">27. listopadu 2019</date>
                     o obezřetnostních požadavcích na investiční podniky a o změně nařízení (EU) č. 1093/2010 (EU) č. 575/2013, (EU) č. 600/2014 a (EU) č. 806/2014 (Úř. věst. L 314, 
                     <date iso="20191205">5.12.2019</date>
                     , s. 1 ).
                  </parg>
               </note>
               <note note.id="E0029" numbering="STAR" type="QUOTATION" class="under">
                  <parg>
                     Směrnice Evropského parlamentu a Rady (EU) 2019/2034 ze dne 
                     <date iso="20191127">27. listopadu 2019</date>
                     o obezřetnostním dohledu nad investičními podniky a o změně směrnic 2002/87/ES, 2009/65/ES, 2011/61/ES, 2013/36/EU, 2014/59/EU a 2014/65/EU (Úř. věst. L 314, 
                     <date iso="20191205">5.12.2019</date>
                     , s. 64).
                     <quotend>"</quotend>
                  </parg>
               </note>
            </quot.s>
         </alinea>
      </article>
 <article identifier="064">
         <ti.art>Článek 64</ti.art>
         <sti.art>Změny nařízení (EU) č. 806/2014</sti.art>
         <alinea>
            <parg>
               V článku 12a nařízení Evropského parlamentu a Rady (EU) č. 806/2014
               <note note.id="E0038" numbering="ARAB" numbering.continued="YES" type="FOOTNOTE">
                  <parg>
                     Nařízení Evropského parlamentu a Rady (EU) č. 806/2014 ze dne 
                     <date iso="20140715">15. července 2014</date>
                     , kterým se stanoví jednotná pravidla a jednotný postup pro řešení krize úvěrových institucí a některých investičních podniků v rámci jednotného mechanismu pro řešení krizí a Jednotného fondu pro řešení krizí a mění nařízení (EU) č. 1093/2010 (
                     <ref.doc.oj coll="L" date.pub="20140730" no.oj="225" page.first="1">Úř. věst. L 225, 30.7.2014, s. 1</ref.doc.oj>
                     ).
                  </parg>
               </note>
               se doplňuje nový odstavec, který zní:
            </parg>
            <quot.s level="1">
               <parag identifier="012A.003">
                  <no.parag>
                     <quotstart>"</quotstart>
                     3.
                  </no.parag>
                  <alinea>
                     <parg>
                        Pokud jde o požadavky na kapitál na individuálním základě investičních podniků uvedených v čl. 2 písm. c) tohoto nařízení, které nejsou investičními podniky uvedenými v čl. 1 odst. 2 nebo 5 nařízení (EU) 2019/2033, jsou v souladu s článkem 65 nařízení Evropského parlamentu a Rady (EU) 2019/2033
                        <note note.id="E0039" numbering="STAR" type="QUOTATION">
                           <parg>
                              Nařízení Evropského parlamentu a Rady (EU) 2019/2033 ze dne 
                              <date iso="20191127">27. listopadu 2019</date>
                              o obezřetnostních požadavcích na investiční podniky a o změně nařízení (EU) č. 1093/2010 (EU) č. 575/2013, (EU) č. 600/2014 a (EU) č. 806/2014 (Úř. věst. L 314, 
                              <date iso="20191205">5.12.2019</date>
                              , s. 1).
                           </parg>
                        </note>
                        v tomto nařízení odkazy na článek 92 nařízení (EU) č. 575/2013 chápány takto:
                     </parg>
                     <list type="alpha">
                        <item>
                           <np>
                              <no.p>a)</no.p>
                              <txt>odkazy na čl. 92 odst. 1 písm. c) nařízení (EU) č. 575/2013, pokud jde o požadavek na celkový kapitálový poměr, v tomto nařízení se považují za odkazy na čl. 11 odst. 1 nařízení (EU) 2019/2033;</txt>
                           </np>
                        </item>
                        <item>
                           <np>
                              <no.p>b)</no.p>
                              <txt>odkazy na čl. 92 odst. 3 nařízení (EU) č. 575/2013, pokud jde o celkový objem rizikové expozice, v tomto nařízení se považují za odkazy na příslušný požadavek podle čl. 11 odst. 1 nařízení (EU) 2019/2033 vynásobený koeficientem 12,5.</txt>
                           </np>
                        </item>
                     </list>
                  </alinea>
                  <alinea>
                     Pokud jde o dodatečné kapitálové požadavky na investiční podniky uvedené v čl. 2 písm. c) tohoto nařízení, které nejsou investičními podniky uvedenými v čl. 1 odst. 2 nebo 5 nařízení (EU) 2019/2034, považují se v souladu s článkem 65 směrnice Evropského parlamentu a Rady (EU) 2019/2034
                     <note note.id="E0040" numbering="STAR" type="QUOTATION">
                        <parg>
                           Směrnice Evropského parlamentu a Rady (EU) 2019/2034 ze dne 
                           <date iso="20191127">27. listopadu 2019</date>
                           o obezřetnostním dohledu nad investičními podniky a o změně směrnic 2002/87/ES, 2009/65/ES, 2011/61/ES, 2013/36/EU, 2014/59/EU a 2014/65/EU (Úř. věst. L 314, 
                           <date iso="20191205">5.12.2019</date>
                           , s. 64).
                           <quotend>"</quotend>
                        </parg>
                     </note>
                     v tomto nařízení odkazy na článek 104a směrnice 2013/36/EU za odkazy na článek 40 směrnice (EU) 2019/2034.
                  </alinea>
               </parag>
               <div>----------------------</div>
               <note note.id="E0039" numbering="STAR" type="QUOTATION" class="under">
                  <parg>
                     Nařízení Evropského parlamentu a Rady (EU) 2019/2033 ze dne 
                     <date iso="20191127">27. listopadu 2019</date>
                     o obezřetnostních požadavcích na investiční podniky a o změně nařízení (EU) č. 1093/2010 (EU) č. 575/2013, (EU) č. 600/2014 a (EU) č. 806/2014 (Úř. věst. L 314, 
                     <date iso="20191205">5.12.2019</date>
                     , s. 1).
                  </parg>
               </note>
               <note note.id="E0040" numbering="STAR" type="QUOTATION" class="under">
                  <parg>
                     Směrnice Evropského parlamentu a Rady (EU) 2019/2034 ze dne 
                     <date iso="20191127">27. listopadu 2019</date>
                     o obezřetnostním dohledu nad investičními podniky a o změně směrnic 2002/87/ES, 2009/65/ES, 2011/61/ES, 2013/36/EU, 2014/59/EU a 2014/65/EU (Úř. věst. L 314, 
                     <date iso="20191205">5.12.2019</date>
                     , s. 64).
                     <quotend>"</quotend>
                  </parg>
               </note>
            </quot.s>
         </alinea>
      </article>`;
    
    let windowInnerWidthy;
    let windowscrollX;

    let tooltips = document.querySelectorAll("note:not(.under) parg");
        tooltips.forEach(element => {
        let tooltip = element.getBoundingClientRect();
        let offset = tooltip.left + windowscrollX;
        let width = tooltip.width;
        let smaller  = (offset + width <= windowInnerWidthy);
            if (!smaller) {
                element.classList.add('edge');
            } else {
               element.classList.remove('edge');
            }
        });     
    tooltips = tooltips;
    
</script>
    <svelte:window bind:innerWidth={windowInnerWidthy} bind:scrollX={windowscrollX}/>
<container>
{@html newInnerHTML}
</container>

 <style>
:global(ti, preamble\.init, visa, sti, gr\.consid\.init, consid, article, ti\.art, sti\.art, parag, alinea, item)
 {
     display: block;
     padding-top: 5px;
     padding-bottom: 5px;
}
:global(no\.p, no\.parag)
  {
     padding-right: 6px;
}
:global(alinea:first-of-type)
  {
     display: inline 
}
:global(doctitle, ti, ti\.art, sti, sti\.art)
  {
     text-align: center;
}
:global(note)
 {
     display: inline-block;
     position: relative;
}
:global(note:not(.under) parg)
  {
     visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
     background-color: black;
     color: #fff;
     padding: 5px 5px;
     border-radius: 6px;
     z-index: 1;
     width: 50vw;
     top: 50%;
}
     
:global(.edge)
  {
    right: 0;
     }
:global(note::before)
  {
     content: attr(note\.id);
    font-size: x-small;
    vertical-align: top;
    color: blue;
    padding-left: 6px;
}
:global(note:hover parg)
  {
    visibility: visible;
}
:global(quot\.s)
  {
    background: #ffe574;
    display: inline-block;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this seems like a working code. I added debounce as well to optimize it a little bit.

Svelte [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/a1b7c962e3ec4e5984f419761e75ebd6?version=3.48.0)

```js
<script>
  import { onMount } from "svelte";

  let newInnerHTML = `<article identifier="061">
         <ti.art>Článek 61</ti.art>
         <sti.art>Změna nařízení (EU) č. 1093/2010</sti.art>
         <alinea>
            <parg>V čl. 4 bodu 2 nařízení (EU) č. 1093/2010 se doplňuje nový podbod, který zní:</parg>
            <quot.s level="1">
               <list type="OTHER">
                  <item>
                     <np>
                        <no.p>
                           <quotstart>"</quotstart>
                           viii)
                        </no.p>
                        <txt>
                           pokud jde o nařízení Evropského parlamentu a Rady (EU) 2019/2033
                           <note note.id="E0028" numbering="STAR" type="QUOTATION">
                              <parg>
                                 Nařízení Evropského parlamentu a Rady (EU) 2019/2033 ze dne 
                                 <date iso="20191127">27. listopadu 2019</date>
                                 o obezřetnostních požadavcích na investiční podniky a o změně nařízení (EU) č. 1093/2010 (EU) č. 575/2013, (EU) č. 600/2014 a (EU) č. 806/2014 (Úř. věst. L 314, 
                                 <date iso="20191205">5.12.2019</date>
                                 , s. 1 ).
                              </parg>
                           </note>
                           a směrnici Evropského parlamentu a Rady (EU) 2019/2034
                           <note note.id="E0029" numbering="STAR" type="QUOTATION">
                              <parg>
                                 Směrnice Evropského parlamentu a Rady (EU) 2019/2034 ze dne 
                                 <date iso="20191127">27. listopadu 2019</date>
                                 o obezřetnostním dohledu nad investičními podniky a o změně směrnic 2002/87/ES, 2009/65/ES, 2011/61/ES, 2013/36/EU, 2014/59/EU a 2014/65/EU (Úř. věst. L 314, 
                                 <date iso="20191205">5.12.2019</date>
                                 , s. 64).
                                 <quotend>"</quotend>
                              </parg>
                           </note>
                           , příslušné orgány ve smyslu čl. 3 odst. 1 bodu 5 uvedené směrnice.
                        </txt>
                     </np>
                  </item>
               </list>
               <div>----------------------</div>
               <note note.id="E0028" numbering="STAR" type="QUOTATION" class="under">
                  <parg>
                     Nařízení Evropského parlamentu a Rady (EU) 2019/2033 ze dne 
                     <date iso="20191127">27. listopadu 2019</date>
                     o obezřetnostních požadavcích na investiční podniky a o změně nařízení (EU) č. 1093/2010 (EU) č. 575/2013, (EU) č. 600/2014 a (EU) č. 806/2014 (Úř. věst. L 314, 
                     <date iso="20191205">5.12.2019</date>
                     , s. 1 ).
                  </parg>
               </note>
               <note note.id="E0029" numbering="STAR" type="QUOTATION" class="under">
                  <parg>
                     Směrnice Evropského parlamentu a Rady (EU) 2019/2034 ze dne 
                     <date iso="20191127">27. listopadu 2019</date>
                     o obezřetnostním dohledu nad investičními podniky a o změně směrnic 2002/87/ES, 2009/65/ES, 2011/61/ES, 2013/36/EU, 2014/59/EU a 2014/65/EU (Úř. věst. L 314, 
                     <date iso="20191205">5.12.2019</date>
                     , s. 64).
                     <quotend>"</quotend>
                  </parg>
               </note>
            </quot.s>
         </alinea>
      </article>
 <article identifier="064">
         <ti.art>Článek 64</ti.art>
         <sti.art>Změny nařízení (EU) č. 806/2014</sti.art>
         <alinea>
            <parg>
               V článku 12a nařízení Evropského parlamentu a Rady (EU) č. 806/2014
               <note note.id="E0038" numbering="ARAB" numbering.continued="YES" type="FOOTNOTE">
                  <parg>
                     Nařízení Evropského parlamentu a Rady (EU) č. 806/2014 ze dne 
                     <date iso="20140715">15. července 2014</date>
                     , kterým se stanoví jednotná pravidla a jednotný postup pro řešení krize úvěrových institucí a některých investičních podniků v rámci jednotného mechanismu pro řešení krizí a Jednotného fondu pro řešení krizí a mění nařízení (EU) č. 1093/2010 (
                     <ref.doc.oj coll="L" date.pub="20140730" no.oj="225" page.first="1">Úř. věst. L 225, 30.7.2014, s. 1</ref.doc.oj>
                     ).
                  </parg>
               </note>
               se doplňuje nový odstavec, který zní:
            </parg>
            <quot.s level="1">
               <parag identifier="012A.003">
                  <no.parag>
                     <quotstart>"</quotstart>
                     3.
                  </no.parag>
                  <alinea>
                     <parg>
                        Pokud jde o požadavky na kapitál na individuálním základě investičních podniků uvedených v čl. 2 písm. c) tohoto nařízení, které nejsou investičními podniky uvedenými v čl. 1 odst. 2 nebo 5 nařízení (EU) 2019/2033, jsou v souladu s článkem 65 nařízení Evropského parlamentu a Rady (EU) 2019/2033
                        <note note.id="E0039" numbering="STAR" type="QUOTATION">
                           <parg>
                              Nařízení Evropského parlamentu a Rady (EU) 2019/2033 ze dne 
                              <date iso="20191127">27. listopadu 2019</date>
                              o obezřetnostních požadavcích na investiční podniky a o změně nařízení (EU) č. 1093/2010 (EU) č. 575/2013, (EU) č. 600/2014 a (EU) č. 806/2014 (Úř. věst. L 314, 
                              <date iso="20191205">5.12.2019</date>
                              , s. 1).
                           </parg>
                        </note>
                        v tomto nařízení odkazy na článek 92 nařízení (EU) č. 575/2013 chápány takto:
                     </parg>
                     <list type="alpha">
                        <item>
                           <np>
                              <no.p>a)</no.p>
                              <txt>odkazy na čl. 92 odst. 1 písm. c) nařízení (EU) č. 575/2013, pokud jde o požadavek na celkový kapitálový poměr, v tomto nařízení se považují za odkazy na čl. 11 odst. 1 nařízení (EU) 2019/2033;</txt>
                           </np>
                        </item>
                        <item>
                           <np>
                              <no.p>b)</no.p>
                              <txt>odkazy na čl. 92 odst. 3 nařízení (EU) č. 575/2013, pokud jde o celkový objem rizikové expozice, v tomto nařízení se považují za odkazy na příslušný požadavek podle čl. 11 odst. 1 nařízení (EU) 2019/2033 vynásobený koeficientem 12,5.</txt>
                           </np>
                        </item>
                     </list>
                  </alinea>
                  <alinea>
                     Pokud jde o dodatečné kapitálové požadavky na investiční podniky uvedené v čl. 2 písm. c) tohoto nařízení, které nejsou investičními podniky uvedenými v čl. 1 odst. 2 nebo 5 nařízení (EU) 2019/2034, považují se v souladu s článkem 65 směrnice Evropského parlamentu a Rady (EU) 2019/2034
                     <note note.id="E0040" numbering="STAR" type="QUOTATION">
                        <parg>
                           Směrnice Evropského parlamentu a Rady (EU) 2019/2034 ze dne 
                           <date iso="20191127">27. listopadu 2019</date>
                           o obezřetnostním dohledu nad investičními podniky a o změně směrnic 2002/87/ES, 2009/65/ES, 2011/61/ES, 2013/36/EU, 2014/59/EU a 2014/65/EU (Úř. věst. L 314, 
                           <date iso="20191205">5.12.2019</date>
                           , s. 64).
                           <quotend>"</quotend>
                        </parg>
                     </note>
                     v tomto nařízení odkazy na článek 104a směrnice 2013/36/EU za odkazy na článek 40 směrnice (EU) 2019/2034.
                  </alinea>
               </parag>
               <div>----------------------</div>
               <note note.id="E0039" numbering="STAR" type="QUOTATION" class="under">
                  <parg>
                     Nařízení Evropského parlamentu a Rady (EU) 2019/2033 ze dne 
                     <date iso="20191127">27. listopadu 2019</date>
                     o obezřetnostních požadavcích na investiční podniky a o změně nařízení (EU) č. 1093/2010 (EU) č. 575/2013, (EU) č. 600/2014 a (EU) č. 806/2014 (Úř. věst. L 314, 
                     <date iso="20191205">5.12.2019</date>
                     , s. 1).
                  </parg>
               </note>
               <note note.id="E0040" numbering="STAR" type="QUOTATION" class="under">
                  <parg>
                     Směrnice Evropského parlamentu a Rady (EU) 2019/2034 ze dne 
                     <date iso="20191127">27. listopadu 2019</date>
                     o obezřetnostním dohledu nad investičními podniky a o změně směrnic 2002/87/ES, 2009/65/ES, 2011/61/ES, 2013/36/EU, 2014/59/EU a 2014/65/EU (Úř. věst. L 314, 
                     <date iso="20191205">5.12.2019</date>
                     , s. 64).
                     <quotend>"</quotend>
                  </parg>
               </note>
            </quot.s>
         </alinea>
      </article>`;

  let windowInnerWidthy;

  const debounce = (func, delay) => {
    let timer;
    return function () {
      const context = this;
      const args = arguments;
      clearTimeout(timer);
      timer = setTimeout(() => func.apply(context, args), delay);
    };
  };

  function calculateTooltips() {
    let tooltips = document.querySelectorAll("note:not(.under) parg");
    tooltips.forEach((element, i) => {
      let rect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
      let rectParent = element.parentElement.getBoundingClientRect();
      let tooltipLeft = rectParent.left + rectParent.width;
      let tooltiWidth = rect.width;
      let tooltipFromRightToEnd = tooltipLeft + tooltiWidth;
      let overflow = tooltipFromRightToEnd + 60 > windowInnerWidthy;
      if (overflow) {
        element.classList.add("flip");
      } else {
        element.classList.remove("flip");
      }
    });
    tooltips = tooltips;
  }

  const debouncedcalculateTooltips = debounce(calculateTooltips, 300);

  onMount(() => {
    calculateTooltips();
    window.addEventListener("resize", debouncedcalculateTooltips);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("resize", debouncedcalculateTooltips);
    };
  });
</script>

<svelte:window bind:innerWidth={windowInnerWidthy} />

<container>
  {@html newInnerHTML}
</container>

<style>
  :global(ti, preamble\.init, visa, sti, gr\.consid\.init, consid, article, ti\.art, sti\.art, parag, alinea, item) {
    display: block;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
  }
  :global(no\.p, no\.parag) {
    padding-right: 6px;
  }
  :global(alinea:first-of-type) {
    display: inline;
  }
  :global(doctitle, ti, ti\.art, sti, sti\.art) {
    text-align: center;
  }
  :global(note) {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
  }
  :global(note:not(.under) parg) {
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: black;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 40vw;
    top: 50%;
  }
  :global(.flip) {
    right: 0;
  }
  :global(note::before) {
    content: attr(note\.id);
    font-size: x-small;
    vertical-align: top;
    color: blue;
    padding-left: 6px;
  }
  :global(note:hover parg) {
    visibility: visible;
  }
  :global(quot\.s) {
    background: #fff8d7;
    display: inline-block;
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `onMount` you can make it in a function and call it reactively:

```js
function calculateTooltips() {
  // code goes here
}

// this line will be called everytime windowInnerWidthy changes
$: windowInnerWidthy, calculateTooltips();
```

Comment: [Stephane Vanraes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11956107/stephane-vanraes) Thank you very much. I have just tested in REPL but unfortunately it does not seem to work. Would you be so kind to provide a full <script> code, please? Thank you very much.